# How do you cancel a scheduled YouTube Video (API v3) from publishing?

Tags: youtube

I am integrating the new YouTube API into my CMS. When I schedule an article with a YouTube video attached, I send a request to YouTube to schedule the video to be published at the same time.

My problem is that after scheduling an article, I want to be able to set the associated YouTube video back to a "private" status and undo the scheduling. Here is the code attempting to do this:

```
$listResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos("status",
array('id' => $videoId));

if (empty($listResponse)) {
    die("Can't find a video with given id");
} 
else {

  $video = $listResponse[0];
  $videoStatus = $video['status'];
  $videoStatus['privacyStatus'] = "private";

  $updateResponse = $youtube->videos->update("status", $video);
  $responseTags = $updateResponse['status']['tags'];
}
```

How can you cancel the scheduling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer as I was writing the question out. To achieve what I am trying to do here, I had to replace this line:

```
$videoStatus['privacyStatus'] = "private";
```

with this line:

```
$videoStatus['publishAt'] = NULL;
```

I hope this is of help to somebody at some point!